# can we use browser other than chrome to load web activity in android

Tags: android, webview

In my app I am trying to open web application which needs flash player but as I am new to android I only know opening web view with chrome client. is there any method to open webview with any other browser instead of chrome.
I am planing to open that web activity in puffin browser as it supports flash player

Answer (score 1):

Write this to open URL in your own webview :

```
web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
```

To enable Javascript :

```
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

When the user clicks a link from a web page in your WebView, the default behavior is for Android to launch an application that handles URLs. Usually, the default web browser opens and loads the destination URL. However, you can override this behavior for your WebView, so links open within your WebView.

**EDIT**

Add this to your code and see if its work:
Make sure shouldOverrideUrlLoading(...) should return false to prevent the default browser from being opened.

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't answer of my question I want to open webview with puffin browser as my client can I do that ? can I restrict webview to open url with a speciefic client ? if yes then how ?

Comment: I can't see where you are using a instance of puffin browser or something else do you have any experience with this type of problem ?